# Interaction effects in Bayesian models?

Tags: bayesian, interaction

Hypothetically, say I have advertising spend as a predictor variable (3 channels) and sales as the response variable. A multiple regressions model would be able to give me a pretty decent estimate of how much "push" each of these channels have on the response variable; however, it would not account for synergistic effects between channels. For example, someone seeing an advertisement in a newspaper at the barbershop then seeing a TV at home might produce stronger influence on the potential customer than simply the sum of their independent effects.

Given that I could have any arbitrary number of advertising channels, I will likely need to use some scalable solution; a design matrix of sorts comes to mind- not sure what this would look like in practice.

I imagine this isn't a crazy idea that no one has had before; drug interactions are an important part of pharmaceutical research where the effect of two drugs could be more akin to the multiplication of their individual effects rather than their sum.

(I'm not sure how to go about this in any sort of model, whether Frequentist or Bayesian; however, in my role we almost exclusively use Bayesian methods via PyMC3 for context.)

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Comment: You could use interactions exactly the same as in frequentist setting. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Tim, I don't know how to do that in either paradigm, which was detailed in the fourth paragraph. The question is "how to execute/design an interaction effect?" Feel free to link your preferred resource.

Comment: you simply create a new feature by multiplying the interacting features.